# Why psycopg2 quoted in a Pipfile

Tags: python, psycopg2, pipfile

my Pipfile looks like

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[packages]
Django = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
"psycopg2" = "*"


[requires]
# our Dockerfile is based on Python 3.7
python_version = "3.7"
```

it's working well but I have a question concerning the double quotes around "psycopg2" that are not present for Django on gunicorn.

Why are they here ?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this file was generated with:

```
pipenv
```

Any keys with numbers are quoted.  It doesn't make a functional difference you can remove the quotes if you want to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Any packages that have numbers in them get put in double-quotes.